# Why the number decrements by one when converting to integer in Perl?

Tags: perl

Why the number decrements by one when converting to integer in Perl?

```
23/20 * 100000000
=> 115000000

int(23/20 * 100000000)
=> 114999999
```

Why?

Comment: I'm getting the same result in Python. What other languages do you mean?

Comment: Also, [int](http://p3rl.org/int) is not casting, it's truncating.

Comment: @choroba: How would you demonstrate that there is anything to be truncated?

Comment: `printf "%.20f\n", 23/20 * 100000000` maybe?

Comment: Another interesting difference between `int(23 * 100000/20)` and `int(23/20 * 100000 )`.

Comment: @TLP, Fun tidbit: gcc refuses to apply commutativity of floating point numbers as an optimization for this reason. A compiler option relaxes this restriction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3/20 is a periodic number in binary just like 1/3 is periodic in decimal. Specifically, 23/20 is equal to

```
     ____
1.0010011 × 2^0
```

It would take infinite resources to store this number as a floating point number. Due to limited resources, a slightly smaller number is stored instead.

```
1.001 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0 × 2^0
```

In decimal:

```
$ perl -e'printf "%.100g\n", 23/20'
1.149999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375
```

You then multiply this by 100000000, which results in even more loss of precision.

```
$ perl -e'printf "%.100g\n", 23/20 * 100000000'
114999999.99999998509883880615234375
```

`int` performs truncation, and `print` performs some rounding. With truncation, you get `114999999`. With rounding, you get `115000000`.

Answer (score 4):

The subexpression "23/20", evaluated first, promotes the whole expression to floating point, and so

```
sprintf( "%30.15f", 23/20 * 100000000)
```

yields

```
114999999.999999985098839
```

while the equivalent

```
sprintf( "%30.15f", 23 * 100000000 / 20)
```

evaluates "23 * 100000000" first, which is evenly divisible by 20, and yields

```
115000000.000000000000000
```